# How do I create Mining System like in DomeKeeper / Wall World?

Tags: unity, tilemap

TL;DR -

I want to create a mining system like in Dome Keeper / Wall World.

---

I'll start with the fact that I'm new to gamedev, and i did a wholeday of research before writing this post.

I want to create a mining system like in Dome Keeper / Wall World.
I mean just the basics, I want the Tiles to contain data, and follow RuleTiles.
For example -
I have a 3X3 tile, meaning it has corners and so on, and I want to be able to break a tile (method of breaking does not matter) after I hit it for example 3 times.
Meaning, each tile, will contain something like `int hp = 3` or something, and OnTriggerEnter2D it will get -1 HP, or something like that.

Now, I've done some research, and i understood that you can create a brush of GameObjects, but the tutorials I've found all refer to a single tile, and not for example some ground tiles that can follow TileRules.

How would you start working on it? is there a good resource to learn this?

Comment: if you're new, perhaps start with something simple that you can find a tutorial on, once you are a bit more advanced you may find it easier to tackle.